# Angular lazyLoading is working from module 1 to module 2, but not a vice versa, why?

Tags: angular, module, routes, lazy-loading

I have an Angular project.
In one of my modules I have a routes, configured in the next way:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: PagesComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      loadChildren: 'app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    },
    {
       path: 'members',
       loadChildren: 'app/pages/members/members.module#MembersModule'
     },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  ],
}];
```

The routes are working good, but there is a problem with lazy loading.

If I navigate to url `/dashboard` and click a routerLink to `/members/add`, The MembersModule is being lazy loaded - everythink is ok.
But if I visit url `/members/add` And then click a routerLink to the `/dashboard`, the page is open instantly, wihout any lazyloading, like it is already loaded.

I don't get why this happens.

**UPDATE:**

At the very-top level is an **AppRoutingModule**:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    canActivate: [LoggedOutGuard],
    loadChildren: 'app/auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'pages',
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule'
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' }
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
  enableTracing: true
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

`PagesCompnent` here is just a simple `router-outlet`

**PagesModule** (the one I showed earlier):

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: PagesComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      loadChildren: 'app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    },
    {
       path: 'members',
       loadChildren: 'app/pages/members/members.module#MembersModule'
     },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  ],
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PagesRoutingModule {
}
```

**DashboardRoutingModule:**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: DashboardComponent
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {
}
```

`DashboardComponent` is a template

**MembersRoutingModule:**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: MembersComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'add',
        loadChildren: 'app/pages/members/add/members-add.module#MembersAddModule'
      },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'add', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'add', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ],
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class MembersRoutingModule {
}
```

`MembersComponent` here is a simple `router-outlet`

**MembersAddModule:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MembersAddRoutingModule,
    ThemeModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    MembersAddComponent,
  ],
})
export class MembersAddModule { }
```

I have tried to make it this way:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: PagesComponent,
  children: [
    {
       path: 'members',
       loadChildren: 'app/pages/members/members.module#MembersModule'
    },
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      loadChildren: 'app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'members', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'members', pathMatch: 'full' },
  ],
}];
```

, but it acts the same...

Comment: i think it is working perfectly fine that is how lazy loading work. load only once when the path is visited for the first time

Comment: Yes, you would be righy, if not a one thing. I am entering the website from the `/members/add` page. (Or refreshing browser, staying on that page). And then I try to navigate to the `/dashboard` url and it is already loaded, but I didn't visit it yet. Why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED:**
I was importing the `DashboardModule` in the `PagesModule`.
Now removed, all works ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Your basic routes (default & error) are redirecting to the dashboard, meaning that whatever you do, the first page to be loaded is the dashboard one.

Try reloading when you're on the members page, then navigating, see what happens.

Comment: Ofcourse, I understand this. But I already am on the `/members/add` page. Refreshing and then navigating to `/dashboard`... and the dashboard is already loaded without lazy loading, why?

Comment: @Sergej then please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: I've added now as much information as you could need